# Uploading jar file and converting it into hash value in html

Tags: html

I have tried to upload a jar file and got the hash using the following code.

```
<form action="/upload/attachment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="jar" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload blacklist</button>
</form>
```

I got the hash value /upload/attachment as 85F1xxxxxxxxxxxxx9xxxxxxxxx653xxxxxA0G2.

How can it store the value in the html page to a variable?

Comment: HTML doesn’t know any such thing as a “variable”. If by _“got the hash using the following code”_ you actually mean you are submitting this form, and get the value shown as the result - well then the first place one would think of were it might make sense to “store” this value, is where it is created - in whatever script is running behind `/upload/attachment`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing in html,pass the value to js file and store it there.